# React & Apollo Client | Query not triggering rerender when served from cache

Tags: reactjs, graphql, client, apollo

I have the following React component that is running a query. In a useEffect hook i'm waiting for the result data, to map it to a new object and feed it into a presentational child component.

```
import Content from './Content'

export const Component: FC<ComponentProps> = ({
  getGenericLandingPageQuery,
  uid,
  id,
}) => {
  const { data, loading } = useQuery(getGenericLandingPageQuery, {
    variables: {
      uid,
      id,
    },
  })

  const genericLandingPageInitialState: GenericLandingPageInitialStateTypes = {
    meta: undefined,
    contentSlices: [],
    // ...more initial state settings
  }

  const [genericLandingPageState, setGenericLandingPageState] = useState(genericLandingPageInitialState)

  /*
   * Page data
   */
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isValid(data)) {
      const contentSlices = isValid(body)
        ? data.body.map((slice: SectionTypes) => {
          const { slice_type } = slice
          return {
            type: slice_type,
            ...slice,
          }
        })
        : []

      const meta: MetaProps = {
        title: cms_meta_title,
        description: cms_meta_description,
        robots: contextMeta.robots ?? cms_meta_robots,
        canonical: cms_meta_canonical_url,
      }
      const newGenericLandingPageState = {
        ...genericLandingPageState,
        meta,
        contentSlices,
      }
      setGenericLandingPageState(newGenericLandingPageState)
    }
  }, [data])

  console.log(genericLandingPageState)

  return (
      <Content
        sections={genericLandingPageState.contentSlices}
        meta={genericLandingPageState.meta}
      />
  )
}
```

If the query is being fetched from the network everything is fine and Content will be rendered with data. When the data is being triggered a second time and the content is being served from the cache the useEffect hook is triggered and setState is being called with the new data.

Unfortunately the console.log just above the render statement won't contain the data that setState is being called with in the hook, but contains the initialState data the state variable has been initialized with.

If I change fetch policy to 'network-only' everything works fine.

Does someone know what is going wrong here?